# FFmpeg remove video frames at specific intervals

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a 2K ProRes 4444 film scan in which every fourth frame is duplicate:

ABC**C**DEF**F**GHI**I**JKL**L** ... etc

Is there an FFmpeg command that can trim every 4th frame? Thankfully it's a silent film, so audio isn't an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `select` filter with a `mod` (modulo) expression to make it evaluate to zero for every fourth frame. Then reset the timestamps (`setpts`) and output again using `prores` as the encoder:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i input.mov \
    -filter:v "select=mod(n+1\,4),setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" \
    -c:v prores \
    out.mov
```